# Map two dictionaries by the highest values

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries with keys of a letter and the values are numbers (occurrences in the message I have)
For example ill have:

```
secretWord = 'cat' 
secret = {'a':123, 't',: 42, 'c' 421}  # => cat
known = {'g':400, 'd': 40, 'o':90}     # => god
```

so what i want to do is find a way to replace the letters of the secretWord with the letters in known by the highest, second, and least numbers. So for example secretWord will become 'god'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order by dictionary keys by values using [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), then join the keys using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> sorted(known, key=known.get, reverse=True)
['g', 'o', 'd']
>>> ''.join(sorted(known, key=known.get, reverse=True))
'god'
```

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know about the sorting of a dictionary, only a list. Thanks